# Sphinx adds span with class colon to the header

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

We have a project which produces html from rst files, using Sphinx. Earlier we used Sphinx version 2.1 and after upgrade to version 6.1.3 a sideeffect occurs where our headers defined like this:

```
:header:
```

are rendered in our html structure as small headers, just like when we used Sphinx 2.1, but **span with class "colon"** is injected by Sphinx right after the header.
Is there a way to stop Sphinx doing that without resorting to hiding it with CSS?

Comment: We wanted to maintain the :header: as simply a specific smaller header, because when we use other headers, corresponding to h6 for instance, we can't have the header use a smaller padding. It's going to be rendered as the smallest header based on the earlier headers in the file. So this ```:header:``` was for us a great way to have a custom smaller header. The old approach which worked can be observed in the header "description", or "availability" under this link:
https://success.medius.com/release-notes/R118/#new-pre-approved-invoices
This is the old build, and this is our intended header.

Comment: Maybe you can use `.. rubric:: Description` (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-rubric).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
:some text:
```

actually starts a [field list](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#field-lists) (in e-mails this would be written: `From: …`).
The text between the colons becomes the "field name", in HTML it becomes a definition list term `<dt>` in a specially styled definition list `<dl>`.

From the question, it is not clear whether the use of `:header:` is abusing the field list syntax to get a section header (or similar) in intended size or if you indeed want a "field list".

For smaller headings, there are alternatives like "rubric" and "topic" directives.

Custom CSS is the recommended way for idividual styling preferences in any case.
The trailing colon of a field name was put in a separte span exactly to enable hiding with custom CSS.

Comment: To me. it is clear that the use of `:header:` as described in the question is indeed abuse of the field list syntax.